# Calculating force with two fulcrums and many forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque, statics

I may not be wording the question the right way.

I have a lever. About 2/3 the way back there is a pivot point. We'll call this B
On the very front (end of the lever) there is a block that the lever rests on. Let's just assume the block is actually a point at the very end of the lever.

I have many points (e.g. 30) of force on both sides of the lever.

I am trying to calculate the down force on a hitch for a travel trailer, and so it will depend how and what I load the trailer with.

The left triangle is a pivot point.

The right block is  just for the lever to rest on.

How much weight is resting on that right block?

I am using Excel, so try to keep it simple.

The different down arrows represent different weights.

[image]

(follow-up questions have been edited)

Comment: Try to give us a picture.

Comment: Assuming the position of all forces are known, you can make use of Newton's First Law (rotational version). This means that at such stable state, sum of all toques around any point would be zero. Whatever fulcrum you want to measure force for, you just need to choose the other fulcrum as the pivot point. Then make sure to add up all the torques due to all forces and put this equal to zero. However you need a second equation (since there are two unknowns : two fulcrums). This second equation would be Newton's First Law (translational version) which  says all forces along y addup to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by fulcrum you mean resting points/pivot points and that the lever is not attached to the fulcra. If it is, then the mass of the fulcrum at the back counts in this equation.

The equation for torque is Torque = Force * distance from pivot. If I apply a force of 10 N 1 m away from the pivot point, then I have 10 Nm of torque. The total torque is simply the sum of all of the torque given your frame of reference. Note that since torque is rotation, forces that go down on different sides of the fulcrum cancel oppose one another.

I don't know how to use Excel, but you would take each element in your force, multiply it by its respective distance from the fulcrum (negative distance would mean to the right or left of the fulcrum, your call) and then sum it all together.

Comment: Sorry, you are right in that:

Comment: "take each element in your force, multiply it by its respective distance from the fulcrum (negative distance would mean to the right or left of the fulcrum, your call) and then sum it all together."

I dont think that takes into account that the weight is spread across multiple points. In other owrds, that would be true if there were only one fulcrum.

Comment: @hippypink whenever a force is spread across multiple points (as in the object actually has an area and is applying pressure) then you assume the object is a point source with the point of applied force being the centre of gravity.

Comment: So how does that turn into a formula?

Comment: Just how I described. The net torque is the summary of all the torque of the system. If you already have the forces and the distances, it's easy. If you dont, then you need to calculate it. Assuming that the force is only the force of gravity, then each torque is T=mgd where d is the distance from the projected centre of mass to the pivot.

Comment: Do you have a simple example? Sorry, I failed math

Comment: You have a 3 m long lever L that sits on a pivot 1 m away from the left. The right end of the lever rests on a block. You have three objects sitting on the lever:
a 2kg weight 0.5 m to the left of the pivot
a 3kg weight 1 m to the right of the pivot
a 5kg weight 2 m to the right of the pivot. This object has a flat bottom. It is a regular square with a base of .2 m.

Let's set the centre (or origin) at the pivot itself. Distance to the left is negative and to the right is positive. Your torque is the force due to gravity times the distance from the pivot.
T1: 2*9.8*-0.5
T2: 3*9.8*1
T3: 5*9.8*2

Comment: The total torque is the addition of all of the calculated torques. If it is positive, it means the torque is going downward on the right side (a clockwise rotation). Since the lever is resting on a block, it cannot rotate clockwise. If the torque is negative, it is to the left of the lever (counterclockwise rotation). The net torque for this problem is positive, and so the lever cannot rotate.

Comment: I have no problems in adding the torques and realizeing if it is positive then it puhes down on the block. Lets say that there's 1000 lbs of torque.

Comment: 1000 lbs of torque does not mean 1000 lbs of weight on the block however.

So what I did was to add all negative forces, and then offset that by the same amount of positive force, so it would equal zero.
Then I took leftover forces and calculated the force between the two points as % distance from block x item weiht. This seemed to be only way to calculate the force for a bridge

Big problem calculating part one, without manually entering in items. Rather, I need a way to automatically calculate this, while then automatically making the bride calculation.